# How to delete the cookie at time of reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, datatable

I have one requirement, at the time of pageloading I'm setting cookie using sessionStorage, once refresh/reload the page I have to delete the cookie.
I tried with the following code, but cookie is not deleting for reload the page,
Can someone help me please,

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('POSummary', JSON.stringify(oData));
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('POSummary'));
        }
    });


} );
```

Thanks

Comment: why use a storage if var lifetime is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete a sessionStorage element you need to do this:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("session-name");

if(sessionStorage.getItem('POSummary') != null)
   sessionStorage.removeItem("POSummary");
```

if you want use cookie instead you must implement this two function:

```
        function create (name, value, days){
            var expires;

            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            } else {
                expires = "";
            }
            document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
        }
        function erase (name){
            create(name, "", -1);
        }
```